# Generating ALL non-isomorphic vertex cuts of a given size

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, algebraic-graph-theory

I am interested in generating all possible non-isomorphic vertex cuts of a given size for a particular family of graphs. The graphs are regular, vertex transitive, and edge transitive.

My main purpose for asking is to investigate the toughness of this family of graphs by calculating the number of components in the $G \setminus S$, where $S$ is a vertex cut. However, given the graph's properties, there is bound to be a lot of overlap in isomorphic vertex cuts, and thus repeated calculations, which I am looking to eliminate.

I've done a fair amount of searching on the web, Arxiv, and Google Scholar, but all the algorithms I am able to find focus on minimum vertex cuts, whereas I am interested in cuts of a given size that may not be minimal.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Are you looking to find all vertex cuts up to conjugacy under the isomorphism group of the graph, or are you looking to find all of the nonisomorphic graphs that are obtained after a vertex cut? In either case, this is computationally difficult, you will probably need to come up with your own algorithm. It will be probably be similar to algorithms for finding all of the cliques, independent sets, etc. up to isomorphism.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Thank you for your reply! I am interest in the first case (vertex cuts up to conjugacy). In terms it being computationally difficult, do you know if taking into consideration the graph's structure (regular, vertex-transitive, edge-transitive) makes a difference?

Comment: The automorphism group of the graph comes into play, but not as simple as using vertex transitivity; for example, if you are classifying vertex cuts of size 3, you need to consider the orbits of triples of vertices under the automorphism group (so if vertex transitive, you can assume a specified vertex is part of the cut; but then you have to work from there)